# Appcelerator String contained an illegal UTF-16 sequence

Tags: javascript, ios, utf-8, titanium, appcelerator

I am using a text area for input with maxLength 140. The input is text + emojis. If user is at 139 character and try to insert an emoji I see a weird character in picture. This character is not showing in console. After this when I click submit button I see a red screen error saying "String contained an illegal UTF-16 sequence."

is there a workaround for removing that incomplete character from string?

[image]